# Can't find valid JDBC driver when deploying Liberty app in Bluemix with ElephantSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

I have a WebSphere Liberty 16.0.0.2 webapp that I develop and run locally on my laptop with Derby DB using JPA to work with the database. I used to deploy it into Bluemix with SQLDB (retired by IBM in May 2016) and it all worked fine with automatic wiring of the service. Since SQLDB is no longer available, the only free SQL I was able to find on Bluemix is ElephantSQL, however the autowiring does not seem to work. Here is the error I get after the deployment:

```
Program error occured: CWWJP0013E: The server cannot locate the java:comp/env/jdbc/TriReplicatorDB data source for the TriReplicatorPersistenceUnit persistence unit because it has encountered the following exception: javax.naming.NamingException: CWNEN1001E: The object referenced by the java:comp/env/jdbc/TriReplicatorDB JNDI name could not be instantiated. If the reference name maps to a JNDI name in the deployment descriptor bindings for the application performing the JNDI lookup, make sure that the JNDI name mapping in the deployment descriptor binding is correct. If the JNDI name mapping is correct, make sure the target resource can be resolved with the specified name relative to the default initial context. [Root exception is com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionException: CWNEN0030E: The server was unable to obtain an object instance for the java:comp/env/jdbc/TriReplicatorDB reference. The exception message was: CWNEN1006E: The server was unable to obtain an object for the jdbc/TriReplicatorDB binding with the javax.sql.DataSource type. The exception message was: java.sql.SQLNonTransientException: DSRA4000E: A valid JDBC driver implementation class was not found for the jdbcDriver jdbcDriver[myDerbyJDBCdriver] using the library com.ibm.ws.classloading.sharedlibrary_79. [/home/vcap/app/wlp/usr/servers/triServer/lib/postgresql-jdbc-9.4.1209.jar]].
```

The way I upload the web app is by packaging the server and using `cf push` command. Here is the resulting server.xml file:

```
<server description="new server">
<!-- Enable features -->
<featureManager>
    <feature>jsp-2.3</feature>
    <feature>concurrent-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jaxrs-2.0</feature>
    <feature>jaxrsClient-2.0</feature>
    <feature>jpa-2.1</feature>
    <feature>appSecurity-2.0</feature>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
    <feature>icap:managementConnector-1.0</feature>
    <feature>appstate-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jdbc-4.1</feature>
    <feature>cloudAutowiring-1.0</feature>
</featureManager>
<httpEndpoint httpPort="${port}" id="defaultHttpEndpoint" host="*"/>
<webContainer deferServletLoad="false" trustHostHeaderPort="true" extractHostHeaderPort="true"/>
<applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean"/>
<!-- This is the application itself -->
<webApplication contextRoot="/" id="Tri-Replicator" location="Tri-Replicator.war" name="Tri-Replicator">
</webApplication>
<jdbcDriver id="myDerbyJDBCdriver">
    <library name="DerbyLib">
        <fileset dir="C:\projects_c\Tri-Replicator-16\db\db-derby-10.11.1.1-bin\lib" includes="derby.jar"/>
        <fileset dir='${server.config.dir}/lib' includes='postgresql-jdbc-9.4.1209.jar'/>
    </library>
</jdbcDriver>
<!-- Use local Derby DB for local testing on laptop, but when deployed into BlueMix this will automatically be rewired to use SQL DB instance -->
<dataSource id="DerbyConnection" jdbcDriverRef="myDerbyJDBCdriver" jndiName="jdbc/TriReplicatorDB">
    <properties createDatabase="create" databaseName="${cloud.services.ElephantSQL-tri-replicator.connection.name}" user="${cloud.services.ElephantSQL-tri-replicator.connection.user}" password="${cloud.services.ElephantSQL-tri-replicator.connection.password}" serverName="${cloud.services.ElephantSQL-tri-replicator.connection.host}" portNumber="${cloud.services.ElephantSQL-tri-replicator.connection.port}"/>
</dataSource>
<include location='runtime-vars.xml'/>
<httpDispatcher enableWelcomePage='false'/>
<config updateTrigger='mbean'/>
<appstate appName='Tri-Replicator' markerPath='${home}/../.liberty.state'/>
```

As an alternative question - can anybody suggest other small free plan for SQL database in Bluemix? PostgreSQL and DB2 do not provide free plans.

Comment: What happened here is that the Liberty buildpack performed auto-configuration on your server.xml and added the correct JDBC driver but forgot to update the `dataSource` element with the right `javax.sql.DataSource` attributes. That looks like a bug. Please report this issue in [Liberty buildpack project](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/ibm-websphere-liberty-buildpack/issues).

Comment: I did submit this as a new issue: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/ibm-websphere-liberty-buildpack/issues/305

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception reported states the following:

```
A valid JDBC driver implementation class was not found 
for the jdbcDriver jdbcDriver[myDerbyJDBCdriver]
```

This exception is saying that it is unable to locate the Connection Pooling DataSource class within the `postgresql-jdbc-9.4.1209.jar`.

WLP is working as design and requires additional configuration in the server.xml since WLP is only able to locate the implementation classes for a certain number of known databases[1]. I reviewed the `postgresql-jdbc-9.4.1209.jar` driver and found the implementation class as the following:

```
org.postgresql.ds.PGPoolingDataSource
```

You should update the server.xml file with the following:

```
javax.sql.DataSource="org.postgresql.ds.PGPoolingDataSource"
```

[1]https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_dep_configuring_ds.html

Comment: The class `org.postgresql.ds.PGPoolingDataSource` does not implement `javax.sql.XADataSource`, so I would not recommend setting the XADataSource implementation to a class that does not implement XADataSource.  There are other attributes such as `javax.sql.DataSource` or `javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource` that could be used instead.

Comment: This is very true and that was a mistake on my part. The PostgreSQL driver doesn't have a XA DataSource class. I have updated the answer to reflect the change. Thanks aguibert!

Comment: Thanks for quick response - it conects works now, except that now I have to manually change the server.xml before I push the app to Bluemix because my local Derby database JDBC driver wont load properly when I have this extra pointer to the Postgres JDBC driver:

`<jdbcDriver id="derbyJDBCdriver" javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource="org.postgresql.ds.PGPoolingDataSource">`
... 
As for the JPA code - I am now fixing issues with the database access since my code that works with Derby and DB2 no longer works with Postgres, but that is another topic...

Comment: Turns out there is an XA driver in the jar file postgresql-jdbc-9.4.1209.jar that is automatically added to the app deployment by Bluemix, so here is what I am using now: `<jdbcDriver id="JDBCdriver" javax.sql.XADataSource="org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource"> ` . This driver is described here: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/development/privateapi/org/postgresql/xa/PGXADataSource.html

Comment: I mentioned in my earlier comment that using XA driver the connection to the database works, however the tables were never created. I fixed it by using the non-XA driver per your earlier suggestion: `<jdbcDriver id="JDBCdriver" 
javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource='org.postgresql.ds.PGConnectionPoolDataSource'>
  <library name="PostgresJDBC">
   <fileset dir='...' includes='...' />
  </library>
 </jdbcDriver>
 <dataSource jdbcDriverRef="JDBCdriver" jndiName="jdbc/TriReplicatorDB" transactional='false'
  type='javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource'>
  <properties ... />
 </dataSource>`

Comment: Thanks for the additional testing and following up. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 4):

For using PostgreSQL (which is the JDBC driver used by ElephantSQL) you need to specify your datasource implementation class name on your `<jdbcDriver>` element:

```
<jdbcDriver id="myDerbyJDBCdriver" javax.sql.DataSource="org.postgresql.ds.PGPoolingDataSource">
  <!-- keep nested stuff the same -->
</jdbcDriver>
```

The reason you need to specify the DataSource impl class for PostgreSQL but not for Derby is because Derby is a "known" database to Liberty, but PostgreSQL.

I'll let Liberty development know about this so PostgreSQL can be added as a "known" database sometime in the future.